# Why I need to Rebuild whole solution when make change in razor cshtml file

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015, rebuild

I wonder why every time I need to rebuild whole solution when I make changes to .cshtml file to see changes on web. It takes so much time and it is annoying when I just want to check some minor change in html (for example adding `<td>` element into table which will be filled with value from model)

Please can somebody explain it to me? I'm not very experienced in this area and I want to understand it more :)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a caching issue?  If you're using Chrome or Firefox, keep the dev tools open and right click the refresh icon in your browser to do a hard reload of the page.

Comment: I´m sure, I always reload page with hard reload and clearing cache. Also tried to restart IIS. It is strange. I also thought it is compiled runtime because of that I posted this question, cos' im confused of it.

Comment: You're hosting it in IIS?  Is the website published to a folder there, or do you host the site out of the source folder?  Does this happen if you use Visual Studio's host process instead of IIS?

Comment: Yes it is hosted in IIS but I don´t know how it is published :( How can I discover please? Sorry for being such unusable in clarifying our working environment. I´m new to this and don't properly understand it :P

Comment: I have this problem as well, with one specific project. Never had this issue before. No idea what's causing it, but it's very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Late for the party?

I had the same issue in VS 2019 RC2 while working with out of the oven, still warm demo project based on the Razor Components App template. For each change to take effect I had to rebuild the project. I excluded browser cache issues and everything else I could think of or found mentioned on the web.

I found that in the .csproj file the razor file extensions was set to .cshtml:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <_RazorComponentInclude>Components\**\*.*cshtml*;</_RazorComponentInclude>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

...while the actual file extensions were .razor. After renaming the .razor files to have .cshtml extension everything worked as expected.

Note, it didn't work the other way around, editing the .csproj file to look for .razor extension because there was a conflict in two stock .target files that I didn't want to touch.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the change.
If it is a razor change, yes you need to build (compile dlls). If it is not, that you don't.
Razor syntax is a view syntax of c#. It is used in views and transformed into html via the Razor View Engine. 
By being C# code, you need to generate it's IL by doing a build or rebuild. Basically you are telling the compiler to generate a new IL based on your changes. Than the web server uses the dlls to run the app.